# Rails - find_by_sql with heredoc raises error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, heredoc, find-by-sql

I have this simple SQL in a heredoc

```
sql = <<-SQL
  SELECT SUM(price) as total_price, 
    SUM(distance) as total_distance, 
    TO_CHAR(date, 'YYYY-MM') as month
  FROM Rides
  WHERE user_id = #{current_user.id}
  GROUP_BY month
SQL
```

and a `find_by_sql(sql)` call

```
Ride.find_by_sql(sql).each do |row|
  "#{row.month}: { total_distance: #{row.total_distance}, total_price: #{row.total_price} }" 
end
```

and it raises error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "GROUP_BY"
LINE 6:         GROUP_BY month
                ^
:         SELECT SUM(price) as total_price, 
          SUM(distance) as total_distance, 
          TO_CHAR(date, 'YYYY-MM') as month
        FROM Rides
        WHERE user_id = 1
        GROUP_BY month
```

As you can see, it interpolates the user_id fine so the issue is not in interpolation.

It works if I assign this SQL to a variable as as string, like so:

```
str = "select sum(distance) as total_distance, sum(price) as total_price, to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM') as month from rides where user_id = #{ current_user.id } group by month"
```

What is  the problem with heredoc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL has a `GROUP BY` clause not `GROUP_BY`.

```
sql = <<-SQL
  SELECT SUM(price) as total_price, 
    SUM(distance) as total_distance, 
    TO_CHAR(date, 'YYYY-MM') as month
  FROM Rides
  WHERE user_id = #{current_user.id}
  GROUP BY month
SQL
```

Comment: Omg :D I knew it was something simple :) Thank you